# Full-Text Index menu option not appearing in SQL Server Management Studio AND error when right clicking a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssms, full-text-search

I am using SQL Server Management Studio Version 11.0.3128.0 and SQL Server 2014 12.0.2361 Web Edition.

I have successfully created a Full Text Catalog following these instructions: [Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view because it is not full-text indexed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003240/cannot-use-a-contains-or-freetext-predicate-on-table-or-indexed-view-because-it/6004248)

When I get to the part to Create a Full Text Index, the GUI menu that appears like this:
[image]

Does not appear. All I get is this:

[image]

Why is that the case? I know I can create it in SQL:

```
create fulltext index on Production.ProductDescription(Description)
key index PK_ProductDescription_ProductDescriptionID`
```

But why won't the menu option show up? Full-Text search is enabled.

**Note:** I don't know if it is related to this error but when I right click on a table in this database, I get the following message (Even though I still get the second menu above after I close the error):

[image]

Comment: Are you able to elevate your privileges on the `master` database?

Comment: Yes, I should be able to do that. Do you think this is a permissions issue?

Comment: Maybe. But you shouldn't be getting those errors from every right click either way, so I'd suggest correcting this before further troubleshooting.

Comment: So I just checked and the user I'm connecting with is set up in `DB_Owner` role...so that's very odd.

Comment: Is Management Studio the Express edition perhaps? Also `db_owner` does not give you `VIEW SERVER STATE` permissions. One is a role within a database and one is a server-wide permission. You are unlikely to get `VIEW SERVER STATE` on web edition because that is typically provided by you to web hosts who also host other customers' databases, and they do what they can to prevent you from seeing anything related to those other customers.